# Ajax / Jquery Add clicked link to text input area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im new to jquery and even newer to ajax so please bear with me here.

I have the following script which fetches data (branch names) asynchronously via database:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pickup").on('keyup',function () {
            var key = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'modal/fetch_branch.php',
                type:'GET',
                data:'keyword='+key,
                beforeSend:function () {
                    $("#results").slideUp('fast');
                },
                success:function (data) {
                    $("#results").html(data);
                    $("#results").slideDown('fast');
                }
            });
        });
    }); 

 <input type="text" class="form-control empty" name="keyword" id="pickup" placeholder="&#xf041;"/>
```

When the user types, `S` as an example all branches containg `S` will be returned as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

### WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO

I need to find a way to modify my script, to

- allow user to click the link, for desired result (branch)
- When link (branch) is clicked **it needs to get appended to the form input field as the value of `pickup`**

Any help or advise on how the above can be achieved, much appreciated.

P.S returned data (names) are `<a>` elements , thus they are links.

Comment: Bind a click on items from `data`

Comment: jquery autocomplete implements this functionality already if you are interested in a pre-packaged solution: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you will read up on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand `data` in `success:function (data)` contains some `<a>` elements, so you need to add a handler to process click on these elements:

```
// use `on` as elements are added dynamically
$( "#results" ).on("click", "a", function() {
    // take `text` of a clicked element and set it as `#pickup` value
    $( "#pickup" ).val( $( this ).text() );
    // return false to prevent default action
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add onclick on the link. Try this

```
<a onclick="func(this);" data-value="Strand">Strand</a>

function func(idn){
    var value = $(idn).attr("data-value");

    $("#pickup).val(value); //assuming that the pickup field has a "pickup" id
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help rapidoodle